# ElasticSearch function score query (range filter)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use document scoring instead of filtering.

As a user I can enter something like buyingPrice (from-to) 50-150€.

This works well with origin,offset,scale - e.g.:

```
 gauss:{
   buyingPrice:{
      origin:100€
      offset:100€
      scale:200€
   }
 }
}
```

Problem is now, when a user only enters one side - e.g. **from** 50€

Expected behavior would be, that all buyingPrices above 50€ get full score. The ones below 50€ get a score lower than the full one.

How can I achieve that with ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filter inside function score, so function score will only affect those documents

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {...},  --> other functions
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "price": {
                "lte": 50
              }
            }
          },
          "gauss": {
            "price": {
              "origin": 50,
              "offset": 0,
              "scale": 200
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: But as I understand that, that document would get a score for all values above 250€, right? Which is not wanted - cause 250€ is still a full score document. Only if value is below 50€ it should start scoring.

Comment: @FabianLurz gauss will apply only on documents scoring 50 and less, so anything above 50 will get score 1

Comment: Ahh - got it - this is due to the filter you have set right? Thank you. Did not understand it immediately